# Node JS, Dotenv variable undefined inside other directory rather than root

Tags: javascript, dotenv

Here is my project structure:

```
\root
 +- \src\helper
 | +- mongoCon.js
 +- .env
```

Inside the .env I have:

```
DB_CONN_STRING=somestring
```

Inside mongoCon.js:

```
const { MongoClient, ServerApiVersion } = require('mongodb');
require('dotenv').config();

const connString = process.env.DB_CONNECTION_STRING;

// Create a MongoClient with a MongoClientOptions object to set the Stable API version
// const client = new MongoClient(connString, {
//     serverApi: {
//       version: ServerApiVersion.v1,
//       strict: true,
//       deprecationErrors: true,
//     }
//   });


console.log(connString)
```

This is returning undefined and I don't know why.

When I put the mongoCon.js on root level the code runs as intended.
I think the problem is related to the path, but I'm not used to js.

Comment: How are you running the code? It doesn't matter where the js file is located, but it does matter in which current working directory you are starting `node`.

Comment: Are the `src` folder and `.env` actually located *inside* the `root` folder? Your indentation does not make that clear.

Comment: I'm running inside helper then using node .\mongoCon.js

Comment: yes, the src and .env are located on root folder

Comment: If the `.env` file is placed in root, you should either run `node src\helper\mongoCon.js` in the root directory, or using `DOTENV_CONFIG_PATH=../../.env node .\mongoCon.js` in the helper directory

Comment: That was the problem, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You just have to use the require like this:

```
require('dotenv').config({ path: '../../.env' });
```